# I tried to append word vector to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to append word vector to dataframe from

```
docs_vectors = pd.DataFrame()

for doc in df1['เนื้อเพลง']:
    temp = pd.DataFrame()
    word_list = word_tokenize(doc)
    doc = [word for word in word_list if word not in stop_word and " " not in word]
    doc = [w for w in doc if not re.match(r'[A-Z]+', w, re.I)]
    try:
        temp = temp.append(pd.Series(word_vec), ignore_index = True)
        word_vec = word_model[doc]
    except:
        pass
    doc_vector = temp.mean()
    docs_vectors = docs_vectors.append(doc_vector, ignore_index = True)
```

and I want to save the word vector to classification the dataset 
but "temp" can't save the word vector to train and result of temp show ...

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

and the shape of docs_vectors is

```
(100, 0)
```

Where is the wrong place, why I can't to append the word vector to dataframe

Comment: can you show your dataframe head?

Comment: You should not use empty except clauses. What if there's an error? You're not able to see that because of the empty `except:`...